# Filling the another input field based on the selection of check box

Tags: jquery

I just want to auto fill input fields based on the selection of checkbox.
Below is the code i am using. Its working fine but the problem is that i want to fill the input field only if the user checked the checkbox. if the user unchecked the check box again i want to remove the values that filled by the selection.

```
<script>
    $('.dtgPaymentDetails').change(function () {

        var flag = false;
        var receiptid = $(this).attr("receiptid");
        var receiptamount = $(this).attr("receiptamt");
        var totalamount = $("#txtTotatAmount").val();
        if (isNaN(parseInt(totalamount)))
        {
            totalamount = 0;
        }
        totalamount = parseInt(totalamount) + parseInt(receiptamount);
        $("#txtTotatAmount").val(totalamount);
        $("#txtNetAmount").val(totalamount);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check value is checked are not.

```
<script>
    $('.dtgPaymentDetails').change(function () {

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var flag = false;
            var receiptid = $(this).attr("receiptid");
            var receiptamount = $(this).attr("receiptamt");
            var totalamount = $("#txtTotatAmount").val();
            if (isNaN(parseInt(totalamount)))
            {
                totalamount = 0;
            }
            totalamount = parseInt(totalamount) + parseInt(receiptamount);
            $("#txtTotatAmount").val(totalamount);
            $("#txtNetAmount").val(totalamount);
        } else {
            $("#txtTotatAmount").val("");
            $("#txtNetAmount").val("");
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: one issue with this code is that if i unchecked one checkbox all the values getting vanished. It should minus only the value that i unchecked. Could u help me in this..

Comment: Can you provide how your html looks